# Arrange records from two columns in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to get records in one column which can be further used for grouping.
1. The records in col1 which are present in col2 (like account) need to replaced by col1 record of similar row value of col2 i.e(aaccounti)
2. The records which are duplicated in col2 such as (joinmuquiz) has to be processed in such a way that second occurance of col1 (joinqui ) value should be replaced with first occurance of col1 (joinmquiz) value and col1 (joinqui) should replace the col2 (joinmuquiz) value

```
 |-----------|--------------|   
 | col1      |    col2      |
 |-----------|--------------|
 |aaccounti  |  account     |
 |account    |  baccountry  |
 |joinmquiz  | joinmuquiz   |
 |joinqui    |  joinmuquiz  |
 |ahanime    |   hanime     |
 ----------------------------
```

Following is the output I expect;

```
 |-----------|--------------|   
 | col1      |    col2      |
 |-----------|--------------|
 |aaccounti  |  account     |
 |aaccounti  |  baccountry  |
 |joinmquiz  | joinmuquiz   |
 |joinmquiz  | joinqui      |
 |ahanime    |   hanime     |
 ----------------------------
```

Comment: Very unclear statement of the problem. Not sure if people can understand it.

Comment: use a self join